# How to open a Xaml page in a separate window Other than MainPage.Xaml

Tags: silverlight, out-of-browser

All the below functionality should be worked in Out-of-Browser mode.
On start of my project there is login page after login in the MainPage.xaml there is a button,on click of this button a new page should be opened with WebBrowser control in the page there is grid control,as the grid selected item changes it should be reflected to the 1st window.

Please help me
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible in silverlight 4.
So I updated my project to silverlight 5 and use Window class for  out-of-browser app. to achieve my requirement

```
      WebBrower wb = new WebBrowser();
                        wb.ScriptNotify += new EventHandler<NotifyEventArgs>(b_ScriptNotify);
                        Window win = new Window();
                        win.Height = 870;
                        win.Width = 600;
                        win.Title = "Site Map";
                        win.Content = wb;
                        win.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

 void b_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToInt32(e.Value).ToString());
        }
```